# R get a simple RStudio snippet to run

Tags: r, function, rstudio, code-snippets

I'm trying to learn how to get RStudio `snippets` to run. Lets say I have a very simple function to determine what is the difference between two vectors:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4)
y <- c(2,3,4,5)

difference <- function(x, y) {
  c(setdiff(x, y), setdiff(y, x))
}

difference(x, y)
#[1] 1 5
```

Now if I want to turn this into a `snippet` I have pasted the following into my snippet file (by running `usethis::edit_rstudio_snippets()`):

```
snippet my_difference
    ${1:name}   <-  function(${2:var},  ${3:var})   {
    c(setdiff(${2:var}, ${3:var}),  setdiff(${3:var},   ${2:var}))
    }
```

where each space is tab delimited. However when I start typing `my_difference`, RStudio does not recognize it as a `snippet`.

Can anyone suggest a fix please?

Comment: I don't really understand why you would want that to be a snippet

Comment: As I stated I want to learn how to use snippets, not just specifically for this basic one. I could put it into .rprofile but I presume snippets are much quicker if you have bigger pieces of code, especially for editing?

Comment: Sure but it's still not a good use for snippets.

Comment: Would you have a rule of thumb for what size/things snippets should be used for? Maybe I should be asking what the difference between them and .rprofiles are? I'm finding it difficult to find much on them although this is helpful https://jozef.io/r906-rstudio-snippets/